# Onde podemos ver a evolução destas 3 medalhas?

Tags: suporte, medalhas

Onde podemos ver a evolução destas 3 medalhas?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Sempre falamos sobre isso no chat e tudo, mas acho que ninguém nunca havia aberto essa pergunta, vai saber porquê. +1

Comment: @Randrade acho que era interessante para nós e para a SE isso, dava-nos motivação para divulgar o site.

Comment: Muitos, [inclusive eu](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer?userid=20615), possuem alguma dessas medalhas, mas não sabem de onde vieram. Já foi comentado que o fato de não ver a evolução se daria justamente por "tentar fraudar", mas o motivo certo nunca foi dito, pelo menos para mim.

Comment: Segundo o [@JNat](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/244/153) a evolução destas medalhas não pode ser seguida.

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi o motivo de não poder ser seguida, mas tudo bem. Já haviam falado isso antes, mas não sabia quem. Agora pelo menos sabemos que não tem como. :p

Comment: @Randrade dá um olhada na outra resposta à pergunta que eu fiz no PL, segue o link do Jnat acima.

Comment: eu cheguei a ver, mas ainda não vi um "motivo" para isso. Creio que se tem como "ganhar a medalha", tem como ver o andamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo o @JNat [nesta postagem](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/244/153), a evolução destas medalhas não pode ser seguida.