# Resposta convertida em comentário automaticamente

Tags: suporte, comportamento, comentários, responder-a-si-mesmo

Ao tentar responder à minha pergunta [Onde podemos ver a evolução destas 3 medalhas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5009/onde-podemos-ver-a-evolu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-destas-3-medalhas) o site transformou a minha resposta num comentário. Algo que nunca tinha visto antes, o que aconteceu?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Eu arriscaria dizer que o sistema considerou sua resposta muito trivial e a converteu em comentário -- ops, minha resposta foi convertida em comment!! :O

Comment: @Math mas é um recurso novo?

Comment: Ah tá, agora sim entendi a pergunta ;) Dei uma procurada aqui e aparentemente não é novo não, olha a data dessa postagem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112742/229289 E aparentemente a resposta deve ser curta e conter um link, não necessariamente uma auto-resposta. PS: o meu primeiro comment não foi convertido, foi uma brincadeira

Comment: @Math estranho, nunca me tinha acontecido. E como é que aparecem respostas de um só linha para analisar na fila de Publicações de baixa qualidade?

Comment: Também não conhecia esse recurso e to tentando achar algum caso assim que não foi convertido em comentário e foi parar na fila de análises. A propósito, na pergunta que você linkou não tem nenhuma informação visível para os mods indicando que ela foi convertida automaticamente, então se isso acontece com frequência não tem como sabermos.

Comment: @Math e a mim agora também não aparece, foi só no momento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como pode ver nesse resposta no Meta.SE: [Answer appears automatically converted as a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/229289), existe um mecanismo do sistema que converte algumas respostas automaticamente em comentários que atendam a determinados critérios.

Um dos critérios é que a resposta possua um link, outro, mais subjetivo, é que seja uma resposta curta. Não necessariamente uma resposta à própria pergunta.

O link em questão está exatamente atrás de censura que você colocou na imagem no corpo da pergunta. Se você tentar responder de novo tirando o link você obterá sucesso.

Comment: Acho que te falta ai um pormenor: "Trivial answers containing a link to another question in the network"...